# selecting all records 14 days from the current date

Tags: sql, oracle, sysdate

I am trying to get all records that have a date not further than 14 days from the current date.

Today's date is 12/7/2021.

When I run the following:

```
select sysdate + 14 from dual
```

I get the following results:

```
12/21/2021 9:16:25 PM
```

Therefore, I should not be getting any records past the above date.

The column I am looking at is eta.  Here is the query:

```
select
  full_name
  eta
from table
where eta > sysdate + 14
```

But when I run that query, I am getting dates as far out as in April and May.

How do I correct this?

Comment: `eta between sysdate and sysdate + 14`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you are doing with `where eta > sysdate + 14` is asking for records with an `eta` greater than 14 days from current database date. What you want is a `between`:

```
select
  full_name
  eta
from table
where eta between sysdate and sysdate + 14
```

This will give you any record with an `eta` between today and 14 days from now.

If you want records up to 14 days into the future, regardless of a lower bound, then you want:

```
select
  full_name
  eta
from table
where eta <= sysdate + 14
```

Comment: Thank you, sir.  I think this solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Should've been

```
where eta <= sysdate + 14
```

as you said that you

> should not be getting any records past the above date.

Comment: Upvote for helping me out, however @Austin had the answer I was looking for.  Thank you.